# PHP Foreach Skip First 6

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I'm doing a foreach, I would like to skip the first six entries. I have this so far, it's just outputting the same one, for the number of entries left, should I be putting the `if($i2==6) continue;` somewhere else?

```
   <?php
               $features = $property->get_features();
               if($lastRec2=count($features)){
                        echo '<div class="row">';
                        $i2=0;
                            foreach($features as $feature2) {
                                $i2++;
                                if($i2==6) continue;
                                if( ($i2 % 3== 1) && ($i2<$lastRec2) ) echo '</div><div class="row">';
                                    echo '<div class="col-md-4 p-b-15"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">'.  $feature .'</div></div>';
                            }
                        echo '</div>';
                     }
                  ?>
```

Comment: you mean `if($i2<=6)` ? with `if($i2==6)` you skip just one entry.

Comment: 1 I don't see where `$feature` is defined in the scope of your loop. 2. Why not use a for loop instead of a foreach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just switch to a for loop. Unless you need the iterator.

```
$features = $property->get_features();
if($lastRec2 = count($features)){
  echo '<div class="row">';
  for ($i2 = 6; $i2 < count($features); ++$i2) {
    if( ($i2 % 3 == 1) && ($i2 < $lastRec2) ) echo '</div><div class="row">';
      echo '<div class="col-md-4 p-b-15"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">'.  $features[$i2] .'</div></div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
if($i2<=6)
    continue;
```

[`continue;`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.continue.php) will stop the rest of the foreach from executing.
Your code will work only once, because `$i2` will be set to `6` only once.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `array_chunk` and `array_slice` to accomplish what you're after:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

```
$features = $property->get_features();

$skipped = array_slice($features, 6);

$chunks = array_chunk($skipped, 3);

foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    echo '<div class="row">';

    foreach ($chunk as $feature) {
        echo '<div class="col-md-4 p-b-15"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">' . $feature . '</div></div>';
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to make your code a little more readable with the HTML you could:

```
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) : ?>

    <div class="row">

        <?php foreach ($chunk as $feature) : ?>

            <div class="col-md-4 p-b-15">

                <div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i>
                </div>

                <div class="checkmark-inner">
                    <?php echo $feature ?>
                </div>

            </div>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>

<?php endforeach;
```

FYI, I'm assuming `$feature2` in you question was a typo. If it wasn't let me know which variable is meant to be what and I'll update my answer.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

first of all, if you want to remove the first six entries, your if is wrong, should be:

```
if($i2 <= 6) continue;
```

If the keys from array are sequencial, could you do this:

```
foreach($features as $key => $feature2) {
    if($key < 6) continue;//0 to 5
```

Unless, your code should work anyway